# kivy app runs without implementing the build() method

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Was wondering why the Kivy code kept on showing me the same black window despite doing some updates on the kv file. Then noticed I had a typo on the `buidl()` method.

From the docs "...*implementing its build() method so it returns a Widget instance (the root of your widget tree)*
...", you have to implement the method.

Why does this code run and give the default black window?

```
# game.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Game(Widget):
    pass


class GameApp(App):
    def buidl(self):
        return Game()


GameApp().run()
```

The kv file

```
#game.kv
<Game>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: .5,.5, 1.0
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: self.size
```

Running kivy `1.11.1` python `3.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy apps have a default `build()` method, which you can see [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/app.py#L582); it just returns an empty widget. Generally kivy has two methods to create the root widget tree, either through overriding `build()` or by defining a root widget in a kv file. For more information see [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#creating-an-application) on creating an application.

Your quote can be found in [kivy basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html), before your quoted sentence:

> Creating a kivy application is as simple as:

I guess the authors decided to keep the basic tutorial easy and did not mention the default implementation of `build`, as it doesn't really do anything useful. They also omitted the kv way of defining the root widget; again I would guess to not overwhelm the reader in this first introduction.

Comment: didn't know about the `default build()` method implementation, now it makes sense why the app runs.

Comment: The pictures example in `/share/kivy-examples/demo/pictures` does have `build()` method, but it does not return a widget. What style of running the application does this fall under?

Comment: @ErikIverson The root widget is created in the kv file, the comment in build function states `#the root is created in pictures.kv`. The `build` function is then used to dynamically add child wiget to that root widget. Looking more closely into the [default build implement](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blame/master/kivy/app.py#L597) it seems to only build a widget if no `self.root` is defined, but is called anyway.